# How are WebAPI routes defined when the controller has no attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am debugging someone elses code that uses WebAPI. The WebApiConfig looks like this:

```
// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/v2/{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

The service method that gets called looks like this:

```
public class DeviceController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
    {
        // do stuff here...
    }
}
```

The above code works, and the controller is correctly called when a request is made. But how does the routing work when attributes are not present in the controller?

edit 1:

Let's say I create a new controller called PlantController:

```
public class PlantController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
    {
         // do stuff here...
    }
}
```

When I call the web service like this:

```
api/v2/plant/test
```

The PlantController is not called. However, when I call the device service, it works:

```
api/v2/device/test
```

Comment: If you compare your controller. You have any annotation set in the "Device" one ?

Comment: @OrcusZ - no, the only annotation present is the HttpGet.

Answer (score 0):

ID is optionnal. So if you call this king of route : `api/v2/device` it will try to call a controller action with this signature :

```
public class DeviceController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        // do stuff here...
    }
}
```

This rule is true for all *HTTP words ( Post, Put etc... )*

Comment: So the call is based on the first part of the name of the controller class, e.g. "Device"? If that's the case, then how come my call to another controller does not work (see edit in OP)?

Answer (score 0):

One use of the http verb attributes is a quasi overload based on the http verb.

Image this function.

```
public class DeviceController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
    {
        // do stuff here...
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        // do stuff here...
    }
}
```

In this example the Get(string id) overload of Get will be called when the http request type is a GET, all non GET request types will be routed to the other `Get()` method.